# Show the message of a editTextField as soon as the keyboard be closed in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

```
class ModalBottomSheet {
  _moreModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    var _enterAmount = '';
    List<String> fruits = ['Abhi', 'Avi', 'Nik', 'Sura'];
    List<String> selectedFruits = [];
    List<String> price = ['1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0'];
    List<String> selectedPrices = [];
    // Add a listener to the focus node

    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
      ),
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext bc) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
              child: Container(
                height: size.height * 0.7,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 167, 162, 147),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: const Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Add Expenses',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                      5), // Adjust the width for the desired space
                              Text(
                                ' ', // Add a space character
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Amount',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color:
                                    Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color:
                                    Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null ||
                                value.isEmpty ||
                                value.trim().length <= 1) {
                              return 'Enter Amount';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _enterAmount = value!;
                          },
                          
                        ),                 
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Center(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              DropDownMultiSelect(
                                onSavePressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                selectedAmountValues: selectedPrices,
                                prices: price,
                                options: fruits,
                                selectedValues: selectedFruits,
                                onChanged: (selectedFruits, selectedPrices) {
                                  print('Selected fruits: $selectedFruits');
                                  print('Selected prices: $selectedPrices');

                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedFruits = selectedFruits;
                                    selectedPrices = selectedPrices;
                                    updatePrices(fruits, price, selectedFruits,
                                        selectedPrices);
                                    // if (selectedFruits.isNotEmpty) {
                                    //   Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    // }
                                  });

                                  print(
                                      'You have selected $selectedFruits fruits with prices $selectedPrices.');
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        PrimaryButton(
                          onTap: () {
                            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                            // _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            // print(_enterAmount);

                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate() &&
                                selectedFruits.isNotEmpty) {
                              _formKey.currentState!.save();
                              final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

                              if (user != null) {
                                //updateAmount();
                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                    .collection('expanses')
                                    .add({
                                  'amount': _enterAmount,
                                  'addedAt': Timestamp.now(),
                                  'paid_to': selectedFruits,
                                  'username': _username
                                });
                                double devidedAmount = int.parse(_enterAmount) /
                                    (selectedFruits.length);
                                for (int i = 0;
                                    i < selectedFruits.length;
                                    i++) {
                                  distribteAmount(
                                      selectedFruits[i], devidedAmount);
                                  print("$i -  ${selectedFruits[i]}");
                                  //}
                                }
                              } else {
                                print('user is registered');
                              }

                              getData();
                              print(_enterAmount +
                                  " " +
                                  selectedFruits.toString());
                              // Dismiss the bottom sheet after adding data
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                              _buildDashboardUI();
                            }
                          },
                          text: 'Add',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void updatePrices(List<String> fruits, List<String> price,
      List<String> selectedFruits, List<String> selectedPrices) {
    if (selectedFruits.isEmpty ||
        selectedFruits.length != selectedPrices.length) {
      // Do nothing if selectedFruits is empty or has mismatched length
      return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedFruits.length; i++) {
      String selectedFruit = selectedFruits[i];
      String selectedPrice = selectedPrices[i];

      int index = fruits.indexOf(selectedFruit);

      if (index != -1) {
        price[index] = selectedPrice;
      } else {
        // Handle the case where the selectedFruit is not found in the fruits list
        print('Selected fruit $selectedFruit not found in the list.');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above is my Model Button Sheet. I want to print the number of the editTextField as soon as the Keyboard be close. Or before calling the DropDownMultiSelect.Sppose i clicked on the editTextField and enter 50 then as soon as i close the keyboard i want to print 50. Or before clicking on DropDownMultiSelect page i want to print 50.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to print the number of the editTextField as soon as the Keyboard be close

**Option 1**:

Using a [`focusnode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html):

first, create a focus node.

```dart
final FocusNode _myFocusNode = FocusNode();
```

next, add a listener:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!_myFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        print('value is ${MY_VALUE}}');
      }
    });
  }
```

assing it:

```dart
TextFormField(
                focusNode: _myFocusNode,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Email',
                ),
              ),
```

**Option 2**

You can use the TextFormField's `onEditingComplete` - however, this will only work once the user presses "enter":

```dart
TextFormField(
    onEditingComplete: () {
    print('onEditingComplete'); // Do something.
}
```

Or, if you want the actual value, use `onFieldSubmitted`:

```dart
TextFormField(
    onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
    print('value $value');
},
```